# val() is not a function when looping through elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to bind a value but I am getting the error below.

> val() is not a function.

Please help me.

```
$(function() {
  $('.pic').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function() {
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var date=$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateObject);
        $(this).attr('id').val(date);
      }
    });
```

Comment: As shown by indenting properly your code, it is missing some })...

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax:

```
$(this).attr('id', date);
```

Comment: Happy I could help. Good day.

Comment: @prasadrao Please don't forget to set this as the correct answer, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).attr('ir', date);`. For info you can find the documentation for attr [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value).

Answer (score 0):

`val` is not a function of `attr`. You can try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.pic').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function() {
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var date=$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateObject);
        $(this).attr('id',date)
      }
    });
```